# Improving the visual of the boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I have plot that includes data from 1967-2018. The boxes are a bit hard to see. Any tips on how to change this plot to make it more readable? Or is the main problem that there is just too big of a time period trying to be displayed?

[image: Boxplot image]

```
ggplot(Cl) +
 geom_boxplot(aes(x=CC_Date, y=CC_PWQMN,fill = Label,group = CC_Date), 
 width=0.5) +
 xlab("") +
 ylab("Cl(mg/l)") +  #\n used for spacing between title and axis
 scale_y_log10(breaks = c(0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000), 
            limits = c(0.1, 1000), labels = c(0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000)) +
 scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1967, 1975, 1983, 1991,1999,2008,2018), 
                 limits = c(1967, 2019)) +
 theme_bw() +
 annotation_logticks(sides="l", size=1) +
theme(text=element_text(family="TNR", size=45)) +
theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = 
element_blank()) +
geom_hline(yintercept=120, colour="black", size=1) +
geom_hline(yintercept=50, linetype="longdash", colour="gray37", size=1) +
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(color="black"),axis.text.y = 
element_text(color="black")) +
theme(panel.border = element_rect(colour="black", size = 1.3))+
theme(legend.position = "none")+
scale_fill_manual(values=c("gray70", "gray35"))
```

Comment: The boxplot image is not visible, and it's advisable to include your code in your question.

Comment: what are you trying to improve specifically? The first thing I notice is that the dark fill of most boxes makes it almost impossible to see the line. Are you wanting the boxes to be bigger? Something else? You could also change your y axis to start at 1

Comment: I am wanting to make the boxes bigger. I have tried to change the width but then boxes over lap one another. This boxplot is just one in a panel of 6, so I have other boxplots that have data around 1.